# Setting up HTTPS on Nginx/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

I need to set up HTTPS for my website (Nginx, Rails 4). I used the directions from [this post](https://gentlenode.com/journal/nginx-2-set-up-an-ssl-certificate-from-startssl/48).

I did everything up until the part where it says "Configure your Nginx server to use the new key and certificate".

The problem is that I don't know exactly what the nginx.conf file should look like. I found [something that says how to set it up for Rails](http://www.norbauer.com/rails-consulting/notes/nginx-ssl-rails.html), and I tried that, but it failed to restart. This is what I added to my file (and it didn't work):

```
server {
  listen 443;
  ssl on;
  # path to your certificate
  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/mysite.com.unified.crt;
  # path to your ssl key
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl.key;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # don’t use SSLv3 ref: POODLE

  # put the rest of your server configuration here.

  #location / {
    # set X-FORWARDED_PROTO so ssl_requirement plugin works
    proxy_set_header X-FORWARDED_PROTO https;

    # standard rails+mongrel configuration goes here.
  }
}
```

Comment: what do u get when u run `sudo nginx -t`

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady I get `nginx: [emerg] "server" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:76
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed`

Comment: where is line 76, and what is above it?

Comment: Line 76 is the first line of the code snippet in the original question (`server {`). Above it is the `http{ }` block with a bunch of stuff inside of it.

Comment: Move the server block inside the http block

Comment: Moved the server block inside the http block. Now I get this error: `nginx: [emerg] PEM_read_bio_X509_AUX("/etc/nginx/ssl/mysite.com.unified.crt") failed (SSL: error:0906D066:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:bad end line)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed`

Comment: could you add the whole `nginx.conf` file